# How to replace no data with 0 using measure in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: Matrix]

I have a matrix that I am using in Power BI visualization.

```
Percentage     Status       
              High  Low   Medium

10%                         1   
20%                  1      
30%            1
```

"1" is the count of values in a column. I want to display 0 where there is no data in the above matrix.

I have tried dong below:

1. Adding +0 at the end of measure.
2. `= IF(CALCULATE(COUNT(Table[col])=ISBLANK()),0,COUNT(Table[col]))`

But, nothing seems to work as it is not considering no data as blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with just a measure. There are no rows of data in the table that correspond to those empty cells, so it doesn't even try to evaluate a measure.

What you can do is create a calculated table and use that in your Columns field.

```
Status = VALUES(Table[Status])
```

Create the relationship from that table to your original table on the `Status` column and replace `Table[Status]` with `Status[Status]` in your matrix visual. Now adding `+0` should do the trick.

```
Measure = COUNT ( Table[col] ) + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the True False condition with ISBLANK(), use directly value as Blank() to compare the cell value,

```
=
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Table[col] )
            = BLANK ()
    ),
    0,
    COUNT ( Table[col] )
)
```

Hope it helps!!

[Please check it here..](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/show-items-with-no-data-as-0-instead-of-blanks/td-p/113160)

Comment: Or `ISBLANK(COUNT(Table[col]))` rather than `COUNT(Table[col]) = BLANK()`.